# Threads for slow operations in MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

When new users register on my site I require them to verify their email by sending them an email with a unique link in it.

If I do this synchronously with the Controller Register Action it takes about 3 - 5 seconds for the page to return as the email method takes some time to complete.

In order to deal with this I am doing this:

```
Thread emailRequestThread = new Thread(() => (new EmailSender()).SendConfirmAdressEmail(user));
emailRequestThread.Start();
```

It is working but is this a bad idea? 
If so how should I accomplish the same result?

Comment: This is fine but personally, I think it is overkill to spin up a thread just to send an email! Threads should be used for long or complex time consuming operations and not simple tasks. Alternatively, try using the async/await approach which is efficient to do things asynchronously. The way you are doing it now - what if you have a surge of users signing up? There will be a time where no threads are available and has to wait for one to be freed to be assigned to do the task. So yes, it can be a problem scalability wise

Comment: Spinning up a `Task` to send a mail shouldn't be *too* bad, but you should be aware that if app pool gets recycled during the process, it will be taken down with everything inside it and the e-mail won't be sent.

Comment: Which .NET framework version are you using?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov .Net 4.5, MVC5

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek This is one of the problem scenarios I see, however it should be very unlikely that the app pool goes down as it just serviced other requests (the registration process) and should have a long timeout left, and if it does happen users have a resend email button they can click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of spinning up a new `Thread` to send mail, i would go with the `async` approach.
What we do here is wrap the `StmpClient.SendAsync` EAP pattern with a `Task` so we can await using its `TaskAwaitable`:

```
public static Task SendAsyncTask(this SmtpClient client, MailMessage message)
{
   TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
   Guid sendGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

   SendCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
   handler = (o, ea) =>
   {
      if (ea.UserState is Guid && ((Guid)ea.UserState) == sendGuid)
      {
         client.SendCompleted -= handler;
         if (ea.Cancelled)
         {
            tcs.SetCanceled();
         }
         else if (ea.Error != null)
         {
            tcs.SetException(ea.Error);
         }
         else
         {
            tcs.SetResult(null);
         }
      }
   };

   client.SendCompleted += handler;
   client.SendAsync(message, sendGuid);
   return tcs.Task;
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
Task sendTask = await client.SendAsyncTask(message);
```